# Issue with fetching updated data just after Update Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am updating using @Modifying and just after update I am fetching data using the repository. But the data fetched is not the updated data but the data before update is done.
When I fetch the same using other GET api then the updated data is fetched but not just after updating in the same method.

My Service class update method:

```
public Response update(Integer value, Long id) {

    repository.updateValue(value, id);
    Response res = repository.findById(id);
    return res;
}
```

My Repository class update method:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update T1 set value = :value where id = :id", 
nativeQuery = true)
int updateValue(Integer value, Long id);
```

As mentioned I am getting the previous values in "res".
Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Is your service annotated with Transactional ?

Comment: Yes. Actually I found the answer just now.
I needed to add clearAutomatically in the @Modifying annotation to refresh the context. LIke this: @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true).
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: If your problem is solved you can post the solution in the answer

Answer (score 5):

After adding clearAutomatically=true in @Modifying annotation the update worked just fine.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "update T1 set value = :value where id = :id", 
nativeQuery = true)
int updateValue(Integer value, Long id);
```